# Time complexity calculation in a nested loop

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I've got the following code

```
1 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
2  for (j = 0; j < i; i++)
3    result = result + 1;
```

I know the time complexity is `O(n^2)` but I'm having trouble calculating it the way we're supposed to as explained by the materials we were given.

The time complexity of a loop, according to said materials, is

```
T = T1 + n(T1 + T2)
```

where `T1` is the loop condition and `T2` is the instruction inside the loop.  When applying it to the exercise I get:

```
T = T1 + n(T1 + T2-3) 
  = T1 + n(T1 + T2 + (1+2+3...+n)(T2 + T3)).
```

As `T1`, `T2` and `T3` are all `O(1)`, we get that

```
T = n * (1+2+3+...+n)
  = n * n * (n+1) / 2 
  = n^3.
```

But that is obviously wrong, so... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting.  I'll be more careful next time :)

Comment: Where did you get `(1+2+3...+n)` from?

Comment: It's the number of times the inner loop runs.  First time 0, second time 1,  third time 2,  and so on up to n times the last time when j = n-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derivation is wrong at the expansion of `T2-3`:

```
T2-3 = T2 + i * ( T2 + T3 )
     < T2 + n * ( T2 + T3 )
     = O(n)
```

You did not analyze the inner loop in isolation but took into account the outer loop iteration a second time in writing down the summation. Therefore you came up with an extra factor of `n`.

Comment: Thanks! I understand it now :D